# How to invalid input after one letter

Tags: javascript, html, css

H-I

This is my input

```css
.centered-name 
{
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}
.group {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
} 
.label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  color: #666666;
  font: 400 26px Roboto;
  cursor: text;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 36px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  transition: .3s ease;
  text-align: center;
}
.input:valid ~ .label 
{
  top: 3px;
  font: 400 26px Roboto;
}


.input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.input:focus ~ .label {
  top: 3px;
  font: 400 26px Roboto;
}
.input:focus ~ .bar:before {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
.bar {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ff5126;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 6px;
  transition: .3s ease;
}
.input:valid ~ .bar
{
  border-bottom: 2px solid #3bb873;
}
```

```html
<div class="centered-name">
    <div class="group">
        <input type="text" minlength="5" dir="rtl" class="input res" id="name" required autocomplete="off" />
        <label class="label res" for="name">Name</label>
        <div class="bar"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When is invaild and you write something (less than 5 Letter) and it get out of focus, the label gets down

I also try

```
.input:invalid ~ .label 
{
  top: 3px;
  font: 400 26px Roboto;
}
```

```css
.centered-name
{
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}
.group {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
} 
.label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  color: #666666;
  font: 400 26px Roboto;
  cursor: text;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 36px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  transition: .3s ease;
  text-align: center;
}
.input:valid ~ .label 
{
  top: 3px;
  font: 400 26px Roboto;
}
.input:invalid ~ .label 
{
  top: 3px;
  font: 400 26px Roboto;
}

.input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.input:focus ~ .label {
  top: 3px;
  font: 400 26px Roboto;
}
.input:focus ~ .bar:before {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
.bar {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ff5126;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 6px;
  transition: .3s ease;
}
.input:valid ~ .bar
{
  border-bottom: 2px solid #3bb873;
}
```

```html
<div class="centered-name">
    <div class="group">
        <input type="text" minlength="5" dir="rtl" class="input res" id="name" required autocomplete="off" />
        <label class="label res" for="name">Name</label>
        <div class="bar"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But again the label goes up before we write anything

How to invalid input after we write a letter?

Comment: You need JS to validate an input, I don't see any

Comment: How? i try that but it does`t work!

Comment: you can use `onchange` or `onkeyup` events to run a function that checks if the input has a specific amount of characters and you can do something like adding classnames when invalid input

Comment: you can use `if($('#name').match(/[a-z]/)){}` this checks if there is a letter inside the input value

Comment: Welcome to SO. A more meaningful title and more context information would help other to better understand your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.. add below js

```js
$('#name').keyup( function() {
   if( this.value.length < 6 ) {
   $('input').blur();
   }
});
```

```css
.centered-name 
{
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}
.group {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
} 
.label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  color: #666666;
  font: 400 26px Roboto;
  cursor: text;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 36px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  transition: .3s ease;
  text-align: center;
}
.input:valid ~ .label 
{
  top: 3px;
  font: 400 26px Roboto;
}


.input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.input:focus ~ .label {
  top: 3px;
  font: 400 26px Roboto;
}
.input:focus ~ .bar:before {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
.bar {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ff5126;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 6px;
  transition: .3s ease;
}
.input:valid ~ .bar
{
  border-bottom: 2px solid #3bb873;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="centered-name">
    <div class="group">
        <input type="text" minlength="5" dir="rtl" class="input res" id="name" required autocomplete="off" />
        <label class="label res" for="name">Name</label>
        <div class="bar"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, i just change "$('input').blur();" and it solve my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

the problem you are having is because you are "abusing" valid for styling

you could change that up to use :placeholder-shown https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-placeholder-shown

if you change in your first example

```
.input:focus ~ .label {
   top: 3px;
  font: 400 26px Roboto;
}
```

to something like

```
.input:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ .label {
    top: 3px;
    font: 400 26px Roboto;
}

.input::placeholder {
    color: transparent;
}
```

and add a placeholder to you input tag